# How to specify a dollar $ symbol in the password in the app.config file in C#

Tags: c#, passwords, app-config, sign, dollar-sign

I'm writing a program using C# in selenium with values in the app config file. The password has an ampersand and a dollar sign. How can I write it?

This is the password: 8wwDqHj#q&$m... And this is how I need to write it in the app config file -

```
<add key="db" value="x;Port=y;Database=z;UserId=qa;Password=8wwDqHj#q&$m;"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you escape the ampersand you'll be fine i.e. use **`&amp;`** instead of **&**. The configuration system will unescape it back to & when, for example, you call `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"]`

e.g.

with a configuration file of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="db" value="x;Port=y;Database=z;UserId=qa;Password=8wwDqHj#q&amp;$m;"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and calling

```
var x = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"];
```

`x` will equal the unescaped `x;Port=y;Database=z;UserId=qa;Password=8wwDqHj#q&$m;`

Comment: Is there a way to escape dollar symbol $ as requested in the OP?

Comment: @Francesco This is from a while ago but I'm sure I would have run the code above. A $ sign shouldn't need escaping just the & (and the 4 other XML chars <,>,',")?

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I clicked while hovering on the screen with a touchpad. Add a blank line so I can remove them